# DataTable columns reappear on show/hide

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

I am hiding columns of dataTable but when i resize browser window they reappear in dataTable.
Here is my code.

```
var hide_core_columns = [0, 1, 2];
$("#entry_fields_multiselect option").each(function(index) {
    showHideColumns(entity_table,"hide",hide_core_columns);
});


function showHideColumns(table,command,columns){
if(command=="show"){
  for   (index = 0; index < columns.length; index++) {
      table.fnSetColumnVis( columns[index], true, false );
  }
 }else{
  for   (index = 0; index < columns.length; index++) {
      table.fnSetColumnVis( columns[index], false, false );
  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? This sounds like you somhow is recreating the dataTable, `fnSetColumnVis` is not resetted if the viewport changes.

Comment: how can i handle fnSetColumnVis so on resizing browser window it does not effect hidden columns

Comment: basically i added some user defined columns at second index of dataTable dynamically which was working fine until i tried to show/hide dataTable defined columns